# Is there a way in Python 3 where only the user account which have dump the data in a file should have access to load the json content

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to store the credentials by dumping encoded username and password(in json format) in a file and later i want to use that file to load the json content.

i am able to successfully do that but i want to know is there a way in python 3 by which only user account which have created the file and dumped the json can load the data

I have used cryptography.fernet import Fernet to encrypt the data. 
Used json.dump and json.load to dump and extract the credentials.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
UsernameByte = username.encode()
EncryptedUsername = f.encrypt(UsernameByte)

PasswordByte = password.encode()
EncryptedPassword = f.encrypt(PasswordByte)
a = EncryptedUsername.decode("utf-8")
b = EncryptedPassword.decode("utf-8")
c = key.decode("utf-8")

DecryptedUsername = f.decrypt(EncryptedUsername)
DecryptedPassword = f.decrypt(EncryptedPassword)
data = {'Username':a , 'Password':b , 'key':c}
with open("C:\test.txt", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)


    with open("C:\test.txt") as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
    EncryptedUsername = data['Username'].encode()
    EncryptedPassword = data['Password'].encode()
    key = data['key'].encode()

    f = Fernet(key)
    DecryptedUsernameByte = f.decrypt(EncryptedUsername)
    DecryptedPasswordByte = f.decrypt(EncryptedPassword)

    DecryptedUsername = DecryptedUsernameByte.decode()
    DecryptedPassword = DecryptedPasswordByte.decode()
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question but it makes it easier for people to read your code if you use standard naming conventions. See PEP8 for them all but the main one is to use `snake_case` for naming variables. `UpperCase` names are usually used for classes/types (note how the syntax highlighting has coloured them differently).

Comment: Thanks @Holloway. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

Python has **os** module to work with files and directory.
You can manage permission and ownership of the file you just created.

For more details refer the official guide https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

File ownership

```
import os
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

uid and gid can be retrieved from below lib

```
import pwd
import grp

uid = pwd.getpwnam("nobody").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("nogroup").gr_gid
```

For file permission

```
os.chmod("filepath", 0o400)
```

Hope this will help.

Edited

NOTE : As Holloway mentioned it will protect the file against the user on the same machine only.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will only give protection against users on the same machine without sudo privileges. Opening the file is trivial if the attacker has access to the machine and the drive itself is not encrypted.

Comment: @Holloway , yes you are absolutely correct. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @Holloway and beer44 for the answer but i am executing it on windows platform and i believe it is for Unix only